# denumerable set: If A, B are denumerable sets, AXB is a denumberable set. Prove ZXN, ZXZ and QXQ are also denumerable sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I prove $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{N}$ part:
$f:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$
such that

$$f:(z,n)\mapsto\begin{cases} (2z,n), & z>0 \\ (2(-z)+1,n), & z\leq 0\end{cases} $$

$f: \text{bijective}, 
\implies (z_1, n_1) \neq (z_2, n_2)
\implies f(z_1, n_1) \neq f(z_2, n_2)
\implies f: \text{injective}$.

$f(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N}) = \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}
\implies \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N}\sim \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \wedge \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \sim \mathbb{N}$

i am not sure how to prove that $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ are denumerable sets.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Let $g:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb N$ be  a bijection. For $a\in \Bbb Z$ and $b\in \Bbb N$ with $\gcd (a,b)=1$ let $f(a/b)=2^{g(a)}3^b.$ Then $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb N$ is injective, proving that $\Bbb Q$ is denumerable

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B$ be denumerable sets, and assume $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{N}$. Then choose bijections $k:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$, $h:A\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$ and $g:B\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be bijections. Then: $$(h,g)\circ k:A\times B\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$$
Is a bijection.